# Integrating forecast into ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to complete my time-based dataframe with a forecast on the given data. My dataframe looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(duration = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005), 
                 values = c(120,130,140,100,150,170), 
                 values2 = c(values = c(10,30,40,10,15,17)))
```

I already calculated the forecast for both variables with:

```
vc <- data.frame(forecast(df$values))
tc <- data.frame(forecast(df$values))
```

But my problem is I want to show the forecast and the observation dataframe in one line chart with `facet_grid` for `values` and `values2`.

I guessed I should melt them together with `rbind`. But this isn't possible because of the different numbers of rows in the dataframes.

So whats the right approach for this?

thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you have a typo, both `tc` and `vc` use `values` instead of `values` and `values2`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is the functioning behind `forecast`.
This is how I would do it.

```
library(reshape2)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

vc <- data.frame(forecast(df$values))
tc <- data.frame(forecast(df$values2))

# Bind them
df2 <- rbind(vc,tc)
# Name them
df2$variable <- c(rep('values', 10), rep('values2', 10)) 
# Assign duration for plotting
df2$duration <- rep(2006:2015, 2) # not sure if the years are correct

# Melt original data

m_df <- melt(df, id = 'duration')
```

We need to use `full_join()` to have both `values` and `Point.Estimate` merged by a duration column that does not have the same values

```
# Plot
ggplot(full_join(m_df, df2),
       aes(duration, value)) +
    facet_wrap(~variable) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() + geom_line(aes(duration, Point.Forecast), col='red')
```

Results

[image]